# Reactjs filter state by key and value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

React Newbie here.

I'm trying to match the value of a specific id located in my state, so I can change some value before updating the database via my api.

The state is

```
state = {
library: []
}
```

and then with when the axios changes the state the array looks something like:

```
0:{_id:"", time:"", value:""},
2:{_id:"", time:"", value:""}
```

When I run console.log, it reads it like this.

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]0: {_id: "5c82803ad634ea0bebfb3eff", time: "2019-03-08T14:46:18.663Z", value:""}1: {_id: "5c827fb9d634ea0bebfb3efe", time: "2019-03-08T14:44:09.818Z", value:""}
```

So basically when I type in a specific input field, identified by it's _id, I need to update the value state of that specific state.

Here's the code I have written so far. _id is the unique key of the input field and event value what I'm typing.

```
updateRead = (_id, event) => {
    console.log(_id);
    console.log(event.target.value)
    this.setState(?????)
};
```

Help would be much appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the array [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method on the `library` array in your state, and just return the elements as is if the `_id` doesn't match, and update the `value` if the `_id` does match.

```
updateRead = (_id, event) => {
  const { value } = event.target;

  this.setState(prevState => ({
    library: prevState.library.map(read => {
      if (read._id !== _id) {
        return read;
      }
      return {
        ...read,
        value
      };
    })
  }));
};
```

Comment: *Wow*, talk about similar code in answers. :-) (I suppose there are only so many ways to do this.) I'll leave my answer anyway because of the explanations, but that's really funny.

Answer (score 2):

Two of the fundamental rules of state in React are:

- [Never modify state directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)
- Use the callback version of `setState` when you're setting state based on existing state ([more](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous))

Separately, you can't access properties on the synthetic event after the event handler has returned, so you'll want to grab the value before calling `setState` (since the call to your callback will be asynchronous).

Within the callback, you copy the array, find the relevant object, copy it, and set the value.

So:

```
updateRead = (_id, event) => {
    const {value} = event.target;
    this.setState(({library}) => ({
        library: library.map(entry => entry._id === _id ? {...entry, value} : entry)
    }));
};
```

`map` creates a new array from the previous array's entries. The callback returns a new object if the IDs match (using property spread notation) with an updated `value`, or the original object (since we don't have to copy objects we aren't modifying).